# Fragment interface/listener works with Activity, but not with another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that also has two fragments inside. And I'm trying to implement the listeners within the two fragments to the parent fragment. However, I'm getting an error on

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof MyPostsUpdateListener) {
        myPostsUpdateListener = (MyPostsUpdateListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement MyPostsUpdateListener");
    }
}
```

I have implemented something similar to this in the same manner with just a different listener, and actually works, but in that case, it is being implemented to an activity, instead of a parent fragment.

Is there any work around to this? Because I'm sure that I have implemented it the same way to some other activity, with the only difference that it is being implemented by an activity, and in this case, which gives an error, by a fragment.

Comment: the above code is in the child fragment or in the parent fragment.

Comment: The code above is in the child fragment. Which I will be using for the parent fragment by adding implements ParentFragment.MyPostsUpdateListener to the parent fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass data back to parent fragment, you can get instance of the parent fragment inside child fragment by calling [getParentFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment()) method.

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {

    private void sendToParentFragment(String data) {
        Fragment fragment = getParentFragment();

        if (fragment instanceof MyPostsUpdateListener) {
            myPostsUpdateListener = (MyPostsUpdateListener) fragment;
            myPostsUpdateListener.onData(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for.